# Only One Type of Downvote is not sufficient

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, voting, down-votes

There are some very well asked questions but the answer can be easily found. On the other hand, a very poorly asked question might contain some very interesting points in it.

Consider the question:

> ### What is the result of 21+12+8?
>
> I am struggling with my cousin's math homework. To find the answer to
>   the following question,   "There are three people named Alice, Bob and
>   Charlie. Their ages are 21, 12 and 8 respectively. A fourth person,
>   Dave's age is the average of the ages of Alice, Bob and Charlie. How
>   old is Dave?"   I need to find the answer to 21+12+8. I know that the plus operator sums the left-hand-side and right-hand-side numbers. But there are three numbers and two operators. How do I find the answer?

And this question:

> ### How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?
>
> *Note: This is a real top question from SO.*
>    I don't want my site to get hacked. Please help me to overcome SQL-Injections.

First one is asked properly, shows a research effort. Second one is asked poorly, but when properly asked, it is one of the best questions in SO.

Now, my proposal is:
There should by more than one downvote. I'm not talking about flags. Not every question that deserves a downvote deserves a close flag as well. If so, why is there a downvote button? Only upvotes and flags would be enough.

Moreover, a big problem of the community is, so called "experts" downvote the questions because of XY problem. This might be a downvote choice as well.

For instance:

- Standard downvote
- XY Problem
- Bad wording
- Improperly written code

could be four choices for downvotes.

Comment: So instead of commenting and flagging you want to downvote a post into the ground. What does that improve?

Comment: Bad wording, if it is the only problem in the question, is a reason for editing, not downvoting. If there are more problems, downvote/closevote according to them, not due to poor wording.

Comment: An XY problem is a great reason to comment and perhaps to close as unclear. But even then, no matter how poor the proposed solution is, if not the asker, someone else might be in a situation where it is the only solution to their problem. Downvote if it indicates poor research.

Comment: Improperly written code should be commented upon, perhaps mentioned / fixed in the answers (if quoted, it definitely should be), but poor coding does not always indicate poor effort. Messy indentation is bad, but a trivial injection attack vector _in PHP_ doesn't mean the coder is lazy to research. And yes, you are free to downvote answerers that propagate bad coding by carelessly copying it from the question.

Comment: What exactly "standard downvote"  stands for? "no research effort, unclear or not useful"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing here are **close** reasons:

> - XY problem -> vote to close as "unclear what you are asking".
> - Improperly written code -> vote to close as "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"
> - Bad wording -> vote to close as "unclear what you are asking".

The other courses of action are posting a comment asking for clarification etc. or editing the question into shape ([thanks Lance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234754/only-one-type-of-downvote-is-not-sufficient/234758?noredirect=1#comment771895_234758)).

No need to complicate things with different types of down-vote.

Comment: My 2c - complicating the d/v system will only serve to reduce the number of downvotes, our best signal for poor and off-topic content. For what? The sake of clarity? We are going to start getting discussions and arguments about what the right d/v type should be.

Comment: @Oded. Indeed. I hadn't considered that aspect.

Comment: Actually, you missed the possibility of editing, which is what should happen to a lot of bad wording questions (if they are clear enough to edit into shape).